# Android Facebook SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to the Facebook API, try to load Facebook profile image to load in imageview but I got error `SkImageDecoder::Factory` returned null.

My code:

```
URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ id + "/picture?type=large");
Bitmap bmp  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
iv1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

This is log I have:

```
10-15 14:05:46.782: D/skia(25501): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-15 14:05:46.782: W/System.err(25501): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-15 14:05:46.782: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6669)
10-15 14:05:46.782: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:972)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16757)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16757)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16757)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16757)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:369)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16757)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:424)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:439)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at com.example.intellitick.a1$3.onComplete(a1.java:197)
10-15 14:05:46.783: W/System.err(25501):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)
10-15 14:05:46.783: D/dalvikvm(25501): threadid=12: exiting
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace from the LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

Ey I just add the next code Hope it helps
[image]

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your contribution to this question, but it's worth knowing we discourage code samples in screenshots. There are code formatting tools provided in the editor, which renders code correctly, and allows readers to copy and paste.